# Why does S3 ETag have extra characters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded a file with aws cli using s3api put-object and the response is like this:

```
{
    "ETag": "\"7bd173e5150f57f8ffe94ad61cd5ea9d\""
}
```

When I calculate the hash locally with md5 I get this:

```
173e5150f57f8ffe94ad61cd5ea9d
```

Why does the ETag have 3 extra characters at the front?  This is a small file (8KB) so it's a single part upload.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't really have 2 extra characters.  There are two things happening, here.

ETags are [required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.19) to be wrapped in `"` quotes, so the ETag of the object is `"7bd173e5150f57f8ffe94ad61cd5ea9d"` -- the quotes are part of the ETag.

And, this output is [JSON](https://json.org), where strings are required to be wrapped in `"` ... so the `"` character in a string must be escaped with a backslash -- e.g. the 5-character string `"foo"` (with the quote characters shown being part of the string itself, as opposed to simply enclosing the string), in JSON, is represented as `"\"foo\""`.

Comment: You might try `--output text` to prevent aws-cli from encoding the output as JSON.  This works for at least some commands, iirc.

Comment: Sorry I made a major typo in the question, I've just updated it.  I understand the quotes.  The issue is the ETag adds `7bd` to the beginning.

Comment: Hmmm.  You have a problem, somehow, with your md5 implementation.  An md5 hash is 32 characters.  Yours is only 29.

Comment: Wow okay.  This was a silly mistake caused by misreading the terminal.  I'll mark this as solved anyway for your kind attempt at helping.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, depending on circumstances, even a "cleaned" ETag may contain something other than an MD5 hash, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Object.html